# Burning Xvid and Dvix Files problems

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning, divx, nero

I am using windows 7 ultimate 64 bit edition and Nero 8.

Recently I noticed that every time I go to nero and burn a dvix/xvid file as a data DVD and try to play it in a dvd player that supports these types it does not load up and play.

I then go to my XP machine with Nero 6 on it and burn the exact same file as a data DVD and it works in the exact same dvd player.

I am not sure why this is happening? I am not sure if it is windows 7, nero 8 or my actual dvd burner that is the problem.

How should I go about and figure out what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: if you haven't already, try burning as slow as possible (on the machine whose burns are failing).  you might also try swapping the win7 dvd burner drive into the winXP machine and trying it there -- if it works on the winXP machine, it's not the drive at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Nero 8 is not Win7 compatible.  There could be an incompatibility that's causing your issue there.  If so, you will have to upgrade to Nero 9 or 10.  I have read of people getting it to work with Win7, but I did not have such success.  I couldn't even get it to install correctly and upgraded to 9.

Comment: It installed on my computer just fine with no problems. I went and download nero 9 light and it seems to have no problem burning the divx files now. I guess I will keep both on since I really only burn data cds most of the time and when I do need something else I will check if nero 8 works for those other types of burning.